# YouCompleteMe and VisualStudioCode fails to identify <future> library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, future, youcompleteme

***YouCompleteMe*** - a code autocompleter for Vim uses Clang (and libtinfo.so.5 ?) to support C languages. It does a great job but fails when i include "future" library in c++. It shows me an error that std::packaged_task, std::promise, std::future are not members of namespace std. The thing is i can compile programs with g++ or clang++ containing future, promise and other objects provided by "future" library. *So why YCM fails to identify member objects of that library?*

***Visual Studio Code*** - a beautiful platform for coding. I added two extensions: Clang extension and a complete support for C/C++ extension. It works well but again fails to identify my "future" library. VSC doesn't error me on inclusion of the future lib, it errors me when i try to create an object provided by that library - std::future, std::promise, etc. *So why even VS fails to identify members of that library?*

***The question is*** - what is going on with this lib and why two platforms fail at the point of creating object of that lib?

***My thoughts:***

1) There can not be an issue with Clang - i can compile programs that contain std::future and std::promise;

2) There can not be an issue with the "future" library itself - i can successfully include it and compile code with it;

3) Maybe its the fault of libtinfo.so.5. By default i have newer one: libtinfo.so.6 (i am on fedora 24); so i manually added libtinfo.so.5 to lib64 directory.

4) I can not find anything similar on the internet about this problem. So it might be a very specific issue?

***EDIT:*** It seems that i can not get it working even on Eclipse IDE for C/C++

Comment: Which version of Clang? Are C++11 mode (or higher) enabled by default in those versions, or in how the plugins uses Clang?

Comment: does YCM have a place to specify compiler flags?

Comment: Clang version is 3.8 c++11 is enabled by -std=c++11 flag at least in ycm_extra_conf.py;

Comment: Yes. Ycm has that. These are the flags passed to it : -Wall, -Wextra, -Werror, -lpthread, -pthread, -fexceptions, -std=c++11, -x, c++;

Comment: Joachim, i do not know how they use clang, i know only that they use clang. But it is strange to me that both platforms fail on the same subject.